# ggplotly display ggplot choropleth map ugly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to make my beautiful ggplot map interactive with a tooltip using ggplotly. But the map rendered with ggploty is not beautiful.

Here is a picture of my map with only ggplot:
[image]

Here is a picture of my map when using ggplotly. It removes the legend and make the map ugly:
[image]

Is there another way of making my ggplot map interactive with a tooltip? And also ggplotly takes some time to render the interactive map:

Here is my sample code for my ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = sdpf_f, aes( fill = n,x = long, y = lat, group = group, text = tooltip)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white") +
   theme_void() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="#c3ffff", high="#0291da",
                        guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top", label.position = "bottom", keywidth = 2,
                                             keyheight = 0.5,
                                             title = "Number of agreements"),na.value="lightgrey"
                       ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_map()
```

Thanks & kind regards,

Akshay

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data and this isn't exactly the same, but it's fairly close to what I think you're expecting.

The libraries:

I called `tidyverse` for the plotting and piping. I called `maps` for the data I used and `plotly` for the Plotly graph.

I used a function that is derived from one of the ways `ggplot` sets the aspect ratio. I know I found this function on SO, but I don't remember who wrote it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(plotly)


map_aspect = function(x, y) {
  x.center <- sum(range(x)) / 2
  y.center <- sum(range(y)) / 2
  x.dist <- ggplot2:::dist_central_angle(x.center + c(-0.5, 0.5), rep(y.center, 2))
  y.dist <- ggplot2:::dist_central_angle(rep(x.center, 2), y.center + c(-0.5, 0.5))
  y.dist / x.dist
}
```

I had to create data as your question is not reproducible. I figured I would include it, so that my answer was reproducible.

```
ms <- map_data("state") %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(str_detect(region, "^a"), 1.0,
                    ifelse(str_detect(region, "^o"), 1.5,
                           ifelse(str_detect(region, "^t"), 2.0,
                                  ifelse(str_detect(region, "^s"), 2.5,
                                                    ifelse(str_detect(region, "^w"),
                                                                      3.0, 
                                                                      NA))))))
```

I modified your `ggplot` call. The only change is `coord_fixed` instead of `coord_map`. I did this so that Plotly could interpret the aspect ratio correctly. Within `coord_fixed`, I used the function `map_aspect`.

```
gp <- ggplot(data = ms, aes(fill = n, x = long, y = lat, 
                          group = group, text = tooltip)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white") +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="#c3ffff", high="#0291da",
                        guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top", 
                                             label.position = "bottom", 
                                             keywidth = 2,
                                             keyheight = 0.5,
                                             title = "Number of agreements"),
                        na.value="lightgrey"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_fixed(with(ms, map_aspect(long, lat)))
```

Then I created a Plotly object. I set some requirements for the layout, as well (horizontal legend at the bottom, with the legend title above the elements—similar to the legend in your `ggplot` call).

```
pp <- ggplotly(gp) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", valign = "bottom",
                       title = list(side = "top"),
                       x = .02),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = F), yaxis = list(showgrid = F),
         showlegend = T)
```

Next, I needed to add the information for the legend. I chose to name the traces (which are split by color). I started by creating a vector of the names of the traces (which is what you see in the legend). I added a "" at the end, so that the NA-colored states wouldn't have a named trace (so they won't show in the legend).

This is likely something you'll need to change for your data.**

```
# the color values and the last one, which is for NAs, no legend
nm <- seq(1, 3, by = .5) %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.1f") %>% append(., "")
```

Then I wanted to ensure that `showlegend` was true for all but the NA (light gray) states. I created a vector of T and F.

```
legs <- c(rep(TRUE, 5), FALSE)
```

Then I added these to the plot.

```
invisible(lapply(1:length(pp$x$data),
              function(i){
                pp$x$data[[i]]$name <<- nm[i]
                pp$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <<- legs[i]
              }))
```

[image]